# 405 Error when I try to access data from an api link

Tags: python, json, api

I am trying to get data from an api, but when I try to access it with the following code I get the message (405 Error The method is not allowed for the requested URL.)

```
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
print(data)
```

Comment: As the error says, method not allowed. Which means get method is not allowed. it maybe only listening to post and other request methods

Comment: Thank you Irfan, you were right. It only listened to POST requests

Answer (score -2):

You can try converting the json to dictionary by rewriting the code as

```
response = requests.get(url)
dict=response.json()
data = dict.text
print(data)
```